# Custom package provider to work around namespace conflicts

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a set of RHEL / CentOS systems where I am using the NetBSD pkgsrc system
to install various packages into a certain tree (e.g. `/opt/local`). I want to
manage this with Puppet. I started out simply using the `pkgin` provider, but
I quickly ran into namespace conflicts. For example, both the yum and pkgin
providers were adding `Package[openssl]`, and they conflicted.

To fix this, I have been trying to use a static prefix on my pkgsrc packages,
then strip it off when it is actually passed to the `pkgin` command for handling.

First, I wrote a define to add the prefix and set the provider.

```puppet
define mypkgin::package($ensure='latest') {

    package { "mypkgin_${title}":
        ensure   => $ensure,
        provider => 'mypkgin',
    }

}
```

This will show up in the namespace as `Mypkgin::Package[openssl]`, which does
not itself conflict with anything. And its goal is to add a resource named
`Package[mypkgin_openssl]`, to not conflict with `Package[openssl]` from yum.

Then, I copied the pkgin provider code and modified it to provide a thing
named `mypkgin`. I have a small method in here to strip the prefix from the
name, and that is used in a few places so that the `pkgin` command receives
the pkgsrc package name instead of the prefixed version.

```rb
require "puppet/provider/package"

Puppet::Type.type(:package).provide :mypkgin, :parent => Puppet::Provider::Package do
  desc "Package management using pkgin/pkgsrc, my local edition."

  # Specify full path since it's not in Puppet's exec path
  commands :pkgin => "/opt/local/bin/pkgin"

  has_feature :installable, :uninstallable, :upgradeable, :versionable

  # Strip prefix off of package name
  def my_pkgname(package)
    package.gsub(/^mypkgin_/, '')
  end

  def self.parse_pkgin_line(package)

    # e.g.
    #   vim-7.2.446 =        Vim editor (vi clone) without GUI
    match, name, version, status = *package.match(/(\S+)-(\S+)(?: (=|>|<))?\s+.+$/)
    if match
      {
        :name     => name,
        :status   => status,
        :ensure   => version
      }
    end
  end

  def self.prefetch(packages)
    super
    # Without -f, no fresh pkg_summary files are downloaded
    pkgin("-yf", :update)
  end

  def self.instances
    pkgin(:list).split("\n").map do |package|
      new(parse_pkgin_line(package))
    end
  end

  def query
    packages = parse_pkgsearch_line

    if packages.empty?
      if @resource[:ensure] == :absent
        notice "declared as absent but unavailable #{@resource.file}:#{resource.line}"
        return false
      else
        @resource.fail "No candidate to be installed"
      end
    end

    packages.first.update( :ensure => :absent )
  end

  def parse_pkgsearch_line
    packages = pkgin(:search, my_pkgname(resource[:name])).split("\n")

    return [] if packages.length == 1

    packages.slice!(-4, 4)

    pkglist = packages.map{ |line| self.class.parse_pkgin_line(line) }
    pkglist.select{ |package| my_pkgname(resource[:name]) == package[:name] }
  end

  def install
    if String === @resource[:ensure]
      pkgin("-y", :install, "#{my_pkgname(resource[:name])}-#{resource[:ensure]}")
    else
      pkgin("-y", :install, my_pkgname(resource[:name]))
    end
  end

  def uninstall
    pkgin("-y", :remove, my_pkgname(resource[:name]))
  end

  def latest
    package = parse_pkgsearch_line.detect{ |package| package[:status] == '<' }
    return properties[:ensure] if not package
    return package[:ensure]
  end

  def update
    pkgin("-y", :install, my_pkgname(resource[:name]))
  end

end
```

Every time I run `puppet agent --test`, it tells me that it has added all of these
packages. So clearly I have some namespace bit wrong. It thinks on each run that
the package either needs to be installed, or upgraded, and it tries to do that.
I assume that in one or more places, I should add or remove calls to
`my_pkgname()`, but I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provider determines which packages are already available on the system by means of prefetching.  It looks like you have not replaced or overridden the bits that will result in that process ultimately relying on the `instances()` method.

Looking at that method, it appears that it will generate instances exactly as the pkgin provider would do, right down to the generated package names.  That's a problem for you, because your scheme involves translating package names.  It's not enough just to translate the names Puppet uses to the native ones -- you must also translate the native ones to the ones you want Puppet to see when you create instances on the provider side.

It looks like `self.parse_pkgin_line()` could be modified pretty easily to prepend the needed prefix to your package names.  That seems like it would be the right thing for it to do, but I'm uncertain whether it would have any undesirable side effects.  It is possible that additional changes will be required as well, such as in `parse_pkgsearch_line()`, but that's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it work by adding a prefix to `:name` in `self.pkgin_parse_line()`, and stripping it when handing off to the `pkgin` binary.